# Single double triode vacuum tube for headphone amp at high voltages

Tags: amplifier, audio, vacuum-tube, preamp, headphones

I'm planning to build a single double triode vacuum tube as I have seen many schematics even though most of them are low voltage (20-40v).  However I didn't seem to find a high voltage single double triode schematic.  I know that double triode can be (and was made that way to do it) used for 2 audio signals. (one triode amplifies one signal only)

To keep it simple, would this schematic be appropriate (and have good results) for a headphone amp.  Filters will be recalculated so don't mind little things in the schematic.  The tube I am planning to use is ECC85  *(very similar to 12AT7)*.

And.. would it amplify the sound without distortion? 
   *( in some cases preamplifier acts more like de-amplifier (lowers the signal) when things are not 'balanced' )*

[image]

EDIT:    I've got an idea.  What if I output the sound from triode to an op-amp?    *(OPA2134)*  Would this work instead of putting a transformer to drive headphones?

Comment: If you want distortion "free" amplification, use silicon and stay within the distortion "free" area. Tubes are there for "better" sound when they distort

Comment: You need an output transformer to match the high output impedance (and high voltage)of the tube with the low impedance (low voltage) of a speaker or headphones. The transformer primary would replace Ra. You can delete Cout and Rout.

Comment: PlasmaHH, that is subjective.  Yes I agree, tubes give distortions but they actually are harmonic distortions at low levels. And they sound quite natural/better to humans so most audio enthusiasts agree - tubes sound better.  Also, they don't sound as thin and as sharp - more mellow if you could say.

Comment: They behave much like a Jfet...or is it the other way around?

Comment: Sparky, could you help me with understanding what transformer should I use?  Have never used it in preamps or in amplifiers (as output transformer) in general.  Do I need a specific value, impedance transformer? Or any transformer will do?

Comment: @Giedrius: for all ways the tubes do distort, you can create an equivalent silicon circuit. It is just that the more simpler silicons don't sound like the tube ones. But you want distortion free, so in the end, both will sound the same.

Comment: It's more like Jfets are 'copying' tubes and they don't really sound like tubes. They sound closer to 'tube' sound than 'regular' PNP transistors but far from the real thing.  Might give more information and a good page with information to read on it if you like. Just say so :)

Comment: Surf the web for "tube output transformers". For a tube like this a 10 watt transformer will do. Because of unknowns you may stumble into, we cannot give you a "complete" answer, as it would be an experiment for us as well.

Comment: PlasmaHH, again you are missing the point. And it's qute off-topic really.  It's not about debating which is better. It's subjective. And no, you can't really create an analog silicon circuit which behaves like tubes easily.
Read here before trying to prove me wrong:
http://kenrockwell.com/audio/why-tubes-sound-better.htm

Comment: I must add that JFET sound is somewhat close to 'tube' sound but not as close as the real thing.  I'm really doing this just for the sake of idea of having a vacuum tube headphone amp.  Will I hear the diference?  Yeah, perhaps but it might not be that big.  Tubes are actually really fun and they each have unique sound (EQ curves) to them. For example you can really bring beatiful, mellow mid ranges to the sound with 12AT7 tube and bass oomph with 12AX7.

Comment: @Giedrius. Forget the transformer if this is just a preamp. Since this is a copy of a functioning circuit, I do not know what help we can offer.

Comment: @Sparky256  10watts?  Are you sure about that?  Why would it need such a high power transformer considering that headphones use 1-2 watts at most?

Comment: @Giedrius since you have drawn the circuit in LtSpice what does the simulation tell you when you put an 8 to 32 ohm load across "out"?

Comment: @Steve G .. Actually I copied it from the internet. Just an example of what I am planning to do.  But it's actually a really good idea you have given me here. Haven't thought of it.

Comment: @Giedrius You should remove the part about _distortion_ in your question. It is obvious from your comments that you _want_ distortion and will not accept advice for solutions with less distortion, so the question as it stands makes no sense.

Comment: @Giedrius. I do not know what is left on the market for tube driven transformers. Remember this is a class 'A' circuit so the transformer will always have a dc current passing through it. Better to slightly oversize the transformer so it does not saturate. But this design is for a preamp, so I am a bit confused.

Comment: @Sparky256  Yes, it is for a preamp.  Would this circuit work in only amplifying signal for use with (let's say..) active speakers?  If that's the case then I might get away with it.  But what I understand is that it cannot load low impedances (or it will 'load' them but have a really low sound) only high ones?

Comment: @Giedrius. Ahem... As a preamp it needs to drive an amplifier (tubes or not), so that speakers or headphone can be driven by the amplifier. You are missing a lot of important details. What device is going to drive this preamp?

Comment: @Sparky256 Computer audio card (audio interface), smartphone and similar.  If I understood what you are asking me correctly *(english is not my main language so I might misread/understand incorrectly some words or phrases, I'm sorry for that)*

Comment: @Giedrius. Those devices already output a signal level of several volts. Also some would have a headphone jack with plenty of signal strength for any power amplifier. You tube preamp WILL have distortion by using sources that already have an output of several volts.

Answer (score 1):

All the values you've chosen are textbook values for a 12AX7 pre-amp stage, so the circuit will work.

The circuit by itself is non-linear because you have none to very little negative feedback. For small signals you'll probably won't notice during a listening test, but the distortion is there. If you like that kind of signal-distortion (many people do) is up to you.

The only way to find that out is to breadboard this circuit and give it a listening test.

Regarding distortion: If you want an as-less-distortion-as-possible amplification tubes are the worst choice. You can compensate the distortion but you'll end up with a circuit that won't sound much different than a 30 cent operational amplifier doing the same gain amplification.

Part of the reason why tubes are still being used in High-End Equipment is because they *do* distort, but in a pleasant way. With the values given in your schematic you'll also get more a kind of coloration instead if harsh distortion.

You've mentioned that the circuit should work as a headphone amp: The tube by itself won't be able to amplify and drive a headphone by itself. It's just a simple triode pre-amp stage after all. You will need a some kind of power amplifier to drive your headphones.

Comment: Remember that [negative feedback](http://www.diyaudio.com/forums/solid-state/94676-bob-cordell-interview-negative-feedback-104.html#post1272628) sounds [bad](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/86-ultra-hi-end-ht-gear-20-000/926202-do-no-negative-feedback-amplifiers-sound-better.html) according to some [connoisseurs](https://www.gearslutz.com/board/geekslutz-forum/719668-am-i-only-one-who-hates-negative-feedback-loops-amps-preamps.html). They think they can hear the ["time smear"](https://web.archive.org/web/20080828160014/http://www.thetadigital.com/reviews/profiles/philosophy-wsr-4.htm).

Comment: @pipe if so these connoisseurs should post their favorite pre-amp topology :-)

Answer (score 0):

Figured I should post my solution to this problem.  To control the gain *(volume)* of the circuit a simple variable resistor/potentiometer must be added before signal goes to the circuit.  The reason why are we lowering the sound is because we don't want to clip the tube too much as the sound might not be as 'smooth' when it has too much distortions (harsh ones especially).  So distortion problem is somewhat solved.  *(tubes give off some distortions naturally, we are trying to avoid only the harsh clipping which could easily happen with a song that has many powerful bass lines)*

Now to really make the circuit work we must add an OP-AMP after the preamp.  We don't want to add a cheap 0.3$ operational amplifier as it really might be the bottleneck in the quality here so OPA2134 is a great candidate here in my opinion.

**Potentiometer--> 12AT7 tube preamplifier--> OPA2134 headphone amp**

I've chosen this circuit as an example:

[image]

What's more - we can use the tube heaters power supply to drive this circuit (*it will work great both with 6v and 12v)* 
OPA2134 is a JFET OP-AMP meaning that it has JFET transistor inputs and they have very high input impedance which should match perfectly with tubes high impedance output.

So basically what we are doing is "isolating" the tube from being affected by headphones very low impedance and effectively boosting the signal and avoiding non-linear amplification.

Comment: You need an op amp that can drive the load. OPA134 is not a good choice for that. If you're using an op amp why the valve?

Comment: OPA134 is often used as a 'high-end' headphone amplifier. How can it not handle the load when it is used for that purpose? Valve (tube, really) is for 'natural' sound or more precisely to give harmonic distortions and tube signature sound. OPA2134 is quite neutral and sounds great. Except it has just a hint of 40-80hz bass boost so it should be great for this purpose